# My AsyncTask class has other threads in it. How can i wait for it and all of its threads to finish before executing a following method?

Tags: android, multithreading

The AsyncTask class starts many other threads because i am using a third party library. I am not sure how many threads the library opens but i want to wait for them all to finish before populating my listview with the data they fetch.

At the moment I am sleeping 10000 milliseconds but this is not practical because I don't know how big the list it.

What is the correct solution for this problem?

```
task = new mTask();
        task.execute(appsList);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                populateList();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private class mTask extends AsyncTask<List<ApplicationInfo>, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<ApplicationInfo>... params) {
            appDataManager = new AppDataManager(MainActivity.this,
                    mySQLiteAdapter, MainActivity.this);
            appDataManager.work(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mySQLiteAdapter.close();
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void populateList() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000)
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Cursor cursor;
                mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
                cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

                ArrayList<String> appsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        appsList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        appsList);
                listContent.setAdapter(adp);
                cursor.close();
                mySQLiteAdapter.close();

                Log.i("finished", "finished");
         }
         });

    }
```

**AppDataManager**

```
public void work(List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
    List<ApplicationInfo> appList = appsList;
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String name = appList.get(i).name;
        String pack = appList.get(i).packageName;
        // TODO AsyncTask
        getHtml(pack, name);
    }

}

public void getHtml(final String pack, final String name) {
    String url = MARKET_URL + pack;
            //AndroidQuery library. fetch html
    aq.ajax(url, String.class, 1000, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String htm, AjaxStatus status) {
            Log.i("status", status.getMessage());
            parseHtml(htm, pack, name);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what does appDataManager do?

Comment: @user1049280 fetch data from the internet

Comment: Does the API for your third-party library have a call-back mechanism to signal completion of the work?

Comment: Does AppDataManager extend Thread?  Can you provide more details on it?

Comment: @TedHopp I have added the contents of appManager to my question

Comment: @elevine I have added the contents of appManager to my question

Comment: use Thread.join or wait/notifiy

Comment: also, quick question, what's the point of an ArrayAdapter if that means turning a cursor into an array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would move the call to `populateList` into the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`. I would also rewrite `populateList` to remove the sleep and assume that it is running on the UI thread (eliminate the `runOnUiThread` call and move the body of the `run` method directly into `populateList`).

Now to prevent the `AsyncTask` from completing `doInBackground` until the `AppDataManager` finishes its work. Start by defining a completion flag and a lock object on which you can synchronize:

```
private class mTask extends AsyncTask<List<ApplicationInfo>, Void, Void> {
    boolean complete;
    static Object LOCK = new Object();
    . . .
}
```

Then modify the `AppDataManager` class to provide a call-back to another object when the work is done. Define a field `callback` and update your api and methods:

```
public void work(List<ApplicationInfo> appsList, Runnable callback) {
    this.callback = callback; // define a field named "callback"
    List<ApplicationInfo> appList = appsList;
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String name = appList.get(i).name;
        String pack = appList.get(i).packageName;
        // TODO AsyncTask
        getHtml(pack, name);
    }

}

public void getHtml(final String pack, final String name) {
    String url = MARKET_URL + pack;
            //AndroidQuery library. fetch html
    aq.ajax(url, String.class, 1000, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String htm, AjaxStatus status) {
            Log.i("status", status.getMessage());
            parseHtml(htm, pack, name);
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.run();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now modify your `doInBackground` method to wait for the flag to be set:

```
protected Void doInBackground(List<ApplicationInfo>... params) {
    appDataManager = new AppDataManager(MainActivity.this,
            mySQLiteAdapter, MainActivity.this);
    appDataManager.work(params[0], new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                complete = true;
                LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    });
    // wait for appDataManager.work() to finish...
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        while (!complete) {
            LOCK.wait();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This should do the job. However, you probably should elaborate on this to deal with errors of various sorts (e.g., provide an error notification mechanism for `AppDataManager`).

**UPDATE** I finally noticed that you are doing five network transactions in `AppDataManager`. So instead of running the callback immediately inside the callback method for `ajax()`, decrement a counter and only call back once the counter reaches 0. Initialize the counter to 5 in `work()` before you enter the loop that calls `getHtml()`. Since the counter will be modified by separate threads, access to it needs to be synchronized. (Alternatively, you can use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for the counter.

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked with a slight modification. because `getHtml()` gets called in a loop, `complete` gets set to true on the first run. I've added a flag to be true when the loop  is executing for the last time. that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

[CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) seems like the solution if you're waiting for threads to reach a common point

Also, instead of creating a thread to call `populatelist()` which is itselt creating the thread `runOnUiThread`, I'd look at [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress)